# BigQuery run different queries based on result of one?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have no idea how to do this and have looked at the if function but can't seem to get it to work. In pseudo code

```
data(if (q1, truequery, falsequery)) select ... from `data`
```

Basically what I want to do is if a query returns a result, run one query and if not run another. Any help/lead would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH tableA AS (
  SELECT 1 AS x
),
tableB AS (
  SELECT 2 AS x
),
truequery AS (
  SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE x = 1
),
falsequery AS (
  SELECT * FROM tableB
)
SELECT * FROM truequery UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM falsequery WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM truequery) = 0
```

Hope this gives you good idea
Please note: output schema for both queries should be same

> could I do all of this within another WITH allTables AS(...) and then run a query on that?

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH tableA AS (
  SELECT 1 AS x
),
tableB AS (
  SELECT 2 AS x
),
truequery AS (
  SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE x = 777
),
falsequery AS (
  SELECT * FROM tableB
),
allTables AS (
  SELECT * FROM truequery UNION ALL 
  SELECT * FROM falsequery WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM truequery) = 0
)
SELECT * FROM allTables
```

Comment: could I do all of this within another `WITH allTables AS(...)` and then run a query on that?

Comment: sure. absolutely!

Comment: How would I use this though to check if a query is successful or not? The `SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE x=1` part is throwing me off.

Comment: see update/addition to my answer - it does exactly what you asked! you do not need to check anything in addition  - just run it :o)

Comment: One last thing, how would I check multiple tables? For example I want to run the same two queries on 10+ tables?

Comment: i am not sure i got the question in your latest comment  - please clarify - but have in mind it is hard to answer new questions in comments - if you feel it is going to be a new question - better to post new one!

Comment: Essentially I will have multiple tables that are constructed in my script. I will need to do this check on each one and then at the end, I will want to query the result of all of them. right now I"m using `with allTables as` and then using a query on that "subquery"

Comment: i am not sure I am following you - and honestly this sounds like a new/different question for me. sorry

Comment: @JoeScotto - you might not found all the answers here (as it is hard to answer follow up comments / questions) - but still consider at least voting up (if not yet) - I think your original question is answered - so it will be fair I think